# LOCAL_LANG localisation is still working on typo3 v10?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have upgraded a website from typo3 v7 to v10,
in this website i have a blog extension tx_t3extblog and an added localisation code with typoscript:

```
_LOCAL_LANG {
    en {
        read_more = read more
    }
    de {
        read_more = weiterlesen
    }
}
```

This code is not running anymore, i don't know why, maybe because this _LOCAL_LANG is not working anymore on typo3 v10 or somthing else?

Comment: `_LOCAL_LANG` is still a valid [property of TypoScript](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/TopLevelObjects/Plugin.html#local-lang-lang-key-label-key). Maybe, the identifier of the label changed? Or the plugin signiture? 'en' seems to be invalid, because it's the 'default'...

Comment: Thanks a lot! i changed en with default and now it works